# Talend - tFileExist both paths to meet the same flow

Tags: talend

I am new to talend and I have a situation which I feel is quite standard but don't seem to find a solution.

1. I need to use the tFileExist component to check if a file does not already exist in the target location.
2. If the file does not exist, then I join the main flow which pulls the data from the  source table and places it in the target location as a file.
3. On the other hand, If the file already exists in the target location, then I need to move that file into another location and then join the same main flow (as in point 2) for pulling the file from the source table and placing it in the target location as a file.

However, I do not seem to be able to connect these 2 alternate paths to the same flow. I searched  for a solution but all the posts talk about taking a alternate flows for the 'exists' and 'not exists' paths.

Any suggestions and guidance would be helpful. Thanks.

I have added a link to the job image.

[Job Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDZ81.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the link "if"

Here the example of the job :

[image]

In your "if" link you put a variable that the component tfileexist allow to use :

- ((Boolean)globalMap.get("tFileExist_1_EXISTS"))

And in the other if link you put it's opposite :

- **!**((Boolean)globalMap.get("tFileExist_1_EXISTS"))

You can replace the tmysqlinput/output by whatever you want (for example a tfileinput/output if you want)

Moreover you can consult the variable that a component you put in your job allow by clicking on the structure button :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Theo. I understand the usage of 'If' conditions and I did have them put  The solution that you have presented duplicates the flow tMySQLInput->tMap->tMySQLOutput. This is what I am trying to avoid. If the further processing is a complex one, I do not want to repeat it twice. Also, any modifications that i might want later would need to be made at both places. I am looking for reusing the same flow instead of duplicating it.Thanks again for your response.

Comment: You don't repeat twice the action. If the first "if" is choose the second will never be executed in the same run. you need to relaunch the job to lunch another branch and this one be ech time unique. it's one OR the other one

Comment: I do understand that at run time either of the 2 flows will be executed and not both. But, I am talking about job designing. I am trying to avoid designing a job which duplicates the same flow at design time. I do not want to maintain the same flow twice in my job.

Comment: I edited, so you can do like that :) with only one branch